# Как поставить галочку на нажатый элемент в MenuStrip?

Tags: c#

Как поставить галочку на нажатый элемент в MenuStrip?

Answer (score 2):

У ToolStripMenuItem есть свойства "CheckOnClick", "Checked" и "CheckState" - соотвественно CheckOnClick ставим в true и выбираем нужно нам начальное значение в CheckState (Indenterminate означает неопределенность (не включено и не выключено)).